# Update view pager indicator from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, fragmentstatepageradapter

i'am tryning to update my view pager indicator from my fragment.
My problem is the project is structured like this:
MainActivity -> FragmentA -> FragmentStatePagerAdapter -> FragmentProduct

**I've tried implementing an interface in the adapter but the adapter isn't able to catch the event, only the mainActivity is catching the event.
So the only thing i want it's to update view pager (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) from the fragment.**

**MainActivity:**

```
public class ProductDetailActivity extends ActivityBase implements ProductFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, TabIndicatorListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
}


@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public void updateTabIndicator(ProductFragment productFragment) {
} }
```

**FragmentA - Set adapter etc etc **

```
public class ProductFragmentDetails extends FragmentBase {

private NavigationHelper navHelper = NavigationHelper.getInstance();

ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;

TabPageIndicator indicator;

List<ProductPagerAdapter.RegisterValue> prices;
private FragmentManager fm;

ProductPagerAdapter pagerUpdater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    createDummyPrices();

    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_details, container);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) mainView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    indicator = (TabPageIndicator) mainView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter = new ProductPagerAdapter(fm, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), indicator, prices);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    return mainView;
}}
```

**FragmentStateAdapter**

```
public class ProductPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter, TabIndicatorListener {

... init vars etc etc 

@Override
public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    super.startUpdate(container);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Integer.toString(position + 1);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    super.finishUpdate(container);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return super.isViewFromObject(view, object);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return super.saveState();
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    super.restoreState(state, loader);
}

/**
 * Get icon representing the page at {@code index} in the adapter.
 *
 * @param index
 */
@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return prices.get(index).icon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return prices.size();    //The number of items in the pagerAdapter must be equal to number of products
}

// Instantiate the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String productPrice = Double.toString(prices.get(position).price);
    return ProductFragment.newInstance(productPrice, "OBS");
}

@Override
public void updateTabIndicator(ProductFragment productFragment) {
}
```

**FragmentProduct**

```
public class ProductFragment extends FragmentBase {
init some vars and fields....

     Context context;
TabIndicatorListener tabIndicatorListener;

 public static ProductFragment newInstance(String price, String observations) {
    ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PRICE, price);
    args.putString(ARG_OBSERVATIONS, observations);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


public ProductFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParamPrice = getArguments().getString(ARG_PRICE);
        mParamObservation = getArguments().getString(ARG_OBSERVATIONS);
    }

    try {
        tabIndicatorListener = (TabIndicatorListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement TabIndicatorListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View productView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

    initViews(productView); //Its initialized the views..

    btnAbsent.setOnClickListener(clickOnBtnAbsent);
    btnValidate.setOnClickListener(clickOnBtnValidate);

    editTxtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(mParamPrice));

    return productView;
}

/**
 * @param productView
 */
private void initViews(View productView) {
    txtViewProductName = (TextView) productView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNameProduct);
    txtViewPrice = (TextView) productView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPrice);
   }

@Override
protected int getActionBarMenuRes() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected int getMainLayoutRes() {
    return 0;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


public View.OnClickListener clickOnBtnAbsent = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tabIndicatorListener.updateTabIndicator(ProductFragment.this);
              //Here is where i want to update my view pager indicator
      }
};

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


       public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm surprised that you didn't encounter problems due to the FragmentManager you used. Instead of :

```
fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

you should use the dedicated FragmentManager for nested fragments:

```
fm = getChildFragmentManager();
```

Secondly, related to the listener target you can use one of the methods of the fragment class, getParentFragment(). This method returns, for nested fragments, the container fragment:

```
// in ProductFragment
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = ((ProductFragmentDetails) getParentFragment()).getListener(); 
}
```

In ProductFragmentDetails you'll have the method:

```
public (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getListener() {
     return (OnFragmentInteractionListener) adapter;
}
```

Comment: Yes was my mistake i forget to change the fragmentManager, i'am also surprised how this works. Ok now i see, but i've doubts, because i will be in the Parent Fragment (Witch generates the adapter) and not in the "FragmentStatePagerAdapter" where i'am able to update the indicator, i can call the interface in the getListener to be catched in the Adapter or you suggest another way? I will try to update the adapter and resend it in this method. Thank you in advance

Comment: @firetrap Maybe my code wasn't clear. When a ProductFragment is created it will access its parent(ProductFragmentDetails) through getParentFragment() and ask an implementation of the  TabIndicatorListener interface(through the getListener()) to post the change indicator event. The ProductFragmentDetails has an implementation of that interface, it's the adapter(ProductPagerAdapter) which implements the interface. So, when you call getListener() on the parent fragment you'll get the adapter reference which handles the change.